# how to exchnage the urls for 2 web applications

Tags: central-administration, administration, backup, url, restore

I have two web applications that can be accessed by the following urls:

1. `http://servername/`
2. `http://servername:8090/`

Now I want to swap the web applications urls. So I am thinking of the following approach:

1. Take a backup of all the site collections on the first and second web application.
2. Permanently delete all the site collections.
3. Restore the backup files of the site collection to the new locations.

Can anyone advise if my above approach is considered valid?

Thanks

Comment: actually, moving content databases method could be much easier!

Comment: @VamsiKK what about the site collections them-selfs ? will they get moved by moving the content DB ?

Comment: Yes, Content DB includes those site collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two easy options i am thinking about.

**Method # 1**

- Make the changes on the AAM and Update the IIS bindings.
- Yo may need to IIS reset at then end.

**Method # 2**

- Detach the Content Database from web App A & web App B
- Now attach Content DB from Web app A to Web App B & From web B to Web App A.

Comment: but i tried my approach on a test server , where i took a backup for all the site collections. then i delete the site collections from the web applications. now i got 2 web applications without any site collections. then i restore the site collection to the desired web application.. and seems it is working well,, so is this a valid approach ? although it might require more effort compare to what u are suggesting ,, but i am more comfortable with it, but not sure if this will cause behind the scene problems ?

Comment: I would say, this approach is doing a simple work in hard way....yesterday in one of my HR session...instructor asked me do you want smarter or hard? so no offense but your method is hard....i would personally go with db detached and attached...5 min total.

Comment: Yes, content DB is much easier. Also, don't forget that you have to install solutions on the new web application. not all solutions are globally deployed! You also need to worry about any web config changes that need to be moved.